# Input of "System.in.read()" in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, input, system.in

When you read from the standard input in Eclipse, where does that input come from?

Comment: Yes, the same console of output.  Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in the same window as the standard console output, but you have to actually type something.

Comment: Oh yes! It didn't work in the first time I tried. I found it is because I didn't press "Enter"...  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

1. Run your program (`right-click project -> 'Run As' -> 'Java Application'`)
2. Click in the 'Console' tab field (`Window -> Open Perspective -> Console`)
3. *Type your input arguments, space-separated, and hit 'Enter'*.  Each line of your input is delimited with 'Enter'-key presses.

**3. is where the inputs come from**

Answer (score 0):

If you mean where is the text displayed, the answer is the Console tab. If you do not see this tab upon execution, go to Window -> Open Perspective -> Console.

Comment: He means where to input text, not where to see output text.

Comment: In that case, the Console tab. If it is not visible, follow the above instructions @Johnny Tse